# How to remove a stale consumer from a kafka broker?

Tags: apache-kafka

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server hostname:port --describe --group sub1
```

Consumer group 'sub1' has no active members.

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server hostname:port --delete --group sub1
```

Option '[delete]' is only valid with '[zookeeper]'.

Note that there's no need to delete group metadata for the new consumer as the group is deleted when the last committed offset for that group expires.

*Also when i try to display my consumer details using zookeeper , It tells consumer "sub1" not available.*

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper hostname:port --describe --group sub1
```

```
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use ZooKeeper (not those using the Java consumer API).

Error: The consumer group 'sub1' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Group information for consumers that use Kafka to manage offsets instead of Zookeeper cannot be deleted with built-in tools. If you read the whole warning when trying to execute

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server hostname:port --delete --group sub1
```

it clearly mentions why group metadata info cannot be deleted:

```
Option '[delete]' is only valid with '[zookeeper]'.
Note that there's no need to delete group metadata for the new consumer as the group is deleted when the last committed offset for that group expires.
```